# After uploading a react app to gh-pages, only the background is showing up.

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I uploaded the project to gh-pages the same way I have in the past and for some reason only the background image is showing. Any help would be appreciated.

https://github.com/jellis720/adoboJoeMockup

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json`, you must set `homepage` to the exact path where you are serving your app as specified [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths). In your case, it should be :

```
"homepage": "https://jellis720.github.io/adoboJoeMockup"
```

and **not** :

```
"homepage": "https://jellis720.github.io/adobojoemockup"
```

You'll also likely need to set the `basename` for `BrowserRouter`, check [this](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and now like before, only the background is showing. When I run it locally on my machine, everything works perfect.