# gh-pages publishing only the background image

Tags: reactjs, typescript, github-pages

I am new to gh-pages and deployed my first site today.
However, only the background image shows up: https://sabago.github.io/sabago-portfolio/

My repo: https://github.com/sabago/sabago-portfolio

Upon googling, I came across: [After uploading a react app to gh-pages, only the background is showing up.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919761/after-uploading-a-react-app-to-gh-pages-only-the-background-is-showing-up) but that wasn't my exact issue.

Everything works fine on localhost.

Any help is much appreciated.

NB: I should add that I see an error in the console. I'm not sure if it's related but it's pointing to my compiler module in tsconfig (esnext).

```
main.9af833d9.chunk.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at Module.21 (main.9af833d9.chunk.js:1)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Object.12 (App.tsx:4)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Module.44 (main.9af833d9.chunk.js:1)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Object.14 (main.9af833d9.chunk.js:1)
    at a ((index):1)
    at t ((index):1)
    at Array.r [as push] ((index):1)
```

My tsconfig

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

package.JSON

```
{
  "homepage": "https://sabago.github.io/sabago-portfolio/",
  "name": "sabago",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/react-burger-menu": "^2.6.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages master -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your built app run locally? That is, can you serve the static content in your `build` folder after you build the app?

Comment: where is your webpack config?

Comment: why do you have app.js and app.tsx?

Comment: @Omer From what I understand TS compiles the tsx files into js. I did not create both.

Comment: @Nick, yes. It runs fine locally in localhost

Comment: Its weird, I try to clone your project and npm i.. and stack with errors of permission

Comment: @Omer, are you trying to say that I have to configure webpack manually? I have read and re-read create-react-app setup docs and nothing like that came

Comment: webpack require configuration.. webpack.config.js.. but you are using CRA so why do you need webpack-cli? in the CRA there is webpack behind.. and also babel. I suggest to remove the webpack-cli.

Comment: OK, before i mess with my package.JSON and potentially break more things by removing webpack-cli, do you think that this is the cause of this issue, or just something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the `gh-pages` package installed, so to deploy your app you should simply have to run the following from the command line in your app directory:

```sh
yarn deploy
```

This will push your `build` directory to github pages. If you haven't built your app yet, you'll need to build it first:

```sh
yarn build && yarn deploy
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I had run "npm run build" then "npm run deploy". But I have also run the above commands, the issue persists. It deploys only the background still.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the actual solution to this is. I fixed it by starting all over, but this time I deployed after creating react app, before coding.